# Loading usercontrol to string and submitting the form within

Tags: asp.net, string, templates, user-controls, url-rewriting

What i'm doing is creating a website where the design is done i html files that are then read into the masterpage using System.IO.StreamReader.
and inside the html templates there are keywords like #USER.LOGIN#
that I replace with functions etc.

The issue is that i'm replacing #USER.LOGIN# With a usercontrol where there is a login form.
I have a function that reads the usercontrol into a string and it works.
but since the usercontrol is loaded to string alle the events are not following.

so when I submit the login form nothing nothing happends (the page posts) but cannot get any of the fields from the form...

NOTE:
i'm using url-rewriting so urls are http://www.domain.com/account/login
where account is account.aspx and login is the mode the account is in.

Code for replacing the keyword in the streamreader loop (pr line)

```
If InStr(line, "#USER.LOGIN#") Then
                    line = line.Replace("#USER.LOGIN#", vbCrLf & userfunc.GetMyUserControlHtml("uc", "account_login.ascx", "/account/login/") & vbCrLf)
                End If
```

And the functions to read usercontrol

```
 Public Shared Function GetMyUserControlHtml(contextKey As String, controllerfile As String, Optional ByVal formaction As String = "")
    Dim myId As Guid = New Guid()
    Return userfunc.RenderUserControl("~\Controllers\" & controllerfile, "", myId, formaction)
End Function

Public Shared Function RenderUserControl2(path As String, Optional ByVal formaction As String = "") As String
    Using pageHolder As New Page(), _
        viewControl As UserControl = DirectCast(pageHolder.LoadControl(path), UserControl), _
        output As New StringWriter(), _
        tempForm As New HtmlForm()
        If formaction <> "" Then
            tempForm.Action = formaction
        Else
            tempForm.Action = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl
        End If
        tempForm.Controls.Add(viewControl)
        pageHolder.Controls.Add(tempForm)
        HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, output, False)
        Dim outputToReturn As String = output.ToString()
        Return outputToReturn
    End Using
End Function
```

How would you guyz do this?
I need the userlogin to be hardcoded in the usercontrol but still be able to place it anywhere using the template keyword.
This will also be used with other functions (newsletter signup, shoutbox etc.)

Comment: Why are you trying to load user control like this? You can always add user controls dynamically to a page...

Comment: i think he is trying to create CMS for users. where in they could dynamically place a login form to any page.

Comment: @PhilipBadilla Even in that case, can't he add user controls dynamically on the page?

Comment: yes it's a cms.
but the prob is not placing the usercontrol the prob is that the forms inside usercontrol does not fire a postback when submitting.

Answer (score 0):

what i would suggest is register you control on the web config..

```
<add tagPrefix="CustomControl" tagName="LogIn" src="~/UserControls/Login.ascx"/>
```

you can still use "#USER.LOGIN#" but instead of replacing it with a control... 
replace it with a something like this

```
<CustomControl:LogIn id="LogIn" runat="server"/>
```

this is just a quick write up.. but you could always try if it works

you can save your HTML like this istead of placing an actual "#USER.LOGIN#"

```
<% =GetLoginControl() %>
```

and then create a public function in your code behind named `GetLoginControl()` and return a response.write of the HTML Mark up you need

Comment: I do have the control regged in the webconfig.
but how do I replace the keyword with <CustomControl:LogIn id="LogIn" runat="server"/> ???
cant just do a normal replace then it will just be added as text

Comment: you can use a page where you send your HTML mark up.. and it returns your HTML with all the Tokens Replaced with the right control..by the way these are just ideas.. ive not tried these...

Comment: but that is kinda what i'm doing where the keyword is replaced by a function that outputs the html from the usercontrol. and it works fine.
the prob is that the form inside the usercontrol does not create a postback when submitted. so can't get all the input values from it...

Comment: how did you call your function GetMyUserControlHtml, you need to call it every page load not just the First Page Load